# Navigation Menu Items have null keys in exported translation files (stf of xlf)

Tags: translation, translation-workbench, navigation-menu

I'm trying to mass-import translations with Translation Workbench for various navigation menus we use in our communities. However, when I export the the bilingual STF or XLF files, the `NavigationMenuItem` have null keys.

**Sample STF file**

[image]

**XLF File**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this known issue that Salesforce has:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001q87WQAQ

I am running into the same issue.

There is a solution of sorts contained in the workaround:

> **RESULT**: The exported file has key "NavigationMenuItem.null" for each Navigation Menu Item, and fails when there are 2 or more rows with that key.
>
> **Workaround**
>
> Remove rows for "NavigationMenuItem" from the Translation file before importing that file.
>
> Translations for Navigation Menu Items can be added through the User Interface.

Comment: Welcome to the site Andy - this got flagged as not being an answer - basically because it was just a link and that's frowned upon as links tend to break. I've edited your answer to include some info from the Known Issue as it may help @jmrjulian.